# TSQL/VB.NET - write stream to a table

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, filestream

Dear Folk's i'm using the following code in order to send the bytes of a picture into the stream table:

```
Dim FirstColumnNames As String = imTable(0) & "_Code, " & imTable(0) & "_Price, " & imTable(0) & "_Title, " & imTable(0) & "_Type, " & imTable(0) & "_Height, " & imTable(0) & "_Width, " & imTable(0) & "_Comments "
Dim FirstFieldsValues As String = "'" & imParam(1) & "', '" & imParam(2) & "', '" & imParam(0) & "', '" & imType.ToString & "', '" & imHeight & "', '" & imWidth & "', '" & imParam(3) & "' "
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & imTable(0) & " (" & FirstColumnNames & ")  VALUES (" & FirstFieldsValues & ") ", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & imTable(0) & " WHERE " & imTable(0) & "_Code = " & "'" & imParam(1) & "'", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
AbsRecord = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar
Dim imGUID As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
Dim SecondColumnNames As String = imTable(1) & "_" & imTable(0) & "_ID , " & imTable(1) & "_GUID "
Dim SecondFieldsValues As String = "'" & AbsRecord & "', '" & imGUID.ToString & "'"
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & imTable(1) & " (" & SecondColumnNames & ")  VALUES (" & SecondFieldsValues & ") ", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() " & "FROM " & imTable(1) & " WHERE " & imTable(1) & "_" & imTable(0) & "_ID = " &AbsRecord, RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
RemoteSQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@" & imTable(1) & "_GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = imGUID
Dim tokenObject As Object = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar()
tokenReader = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
tokenReader.Read()
filePathName = tokenReader.GetSqlString(1)
fileToken = DirectCast(tokenReader(3), Byte())
tokenReader.Close()
Dim sqlFile As SqlFileStream = New SqlFileStream(filePathName.Value, fileToken.Value, FileAccess.Write)
```

The tables have the fllowing stracture
Thats the First Table:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " & TablesStat(0, 0) & _
                    " (" & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Code varchar(20) NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Price money NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Title varchar(50) NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Type sql_variant NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Height int NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Width int NULL, " & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_Comments nvarchar(MAX) NULL)", RemoteSQLConn)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

End the second table is:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " & TablesStat(1, 0) & _
   " (" & TablesStat(1, 0) & "_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), " & TablesStat(1, 0) & "_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE , " & TablesStat(1, 0) & "_" & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES " & TablesStat(0, 0) & " (" & TablesStat(0, 0) & "_ID) NOT NULL, " & TablesStat(1, 0) & "_Image varbinary(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL ) ", RemoteSQLConn)

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

My problem comes when i'm trying to read the 'filePathName' and the 'fileToken'
the privious SELECT GET_FILESTREAM.... return me only one colomn to read the colomn 0 which has the GUID in binary format 
I know i'm doing something wrong but i don't know what

My issue is that i'm not geting th 'filePathName' and the fileToken'

is there anybody to assist me?

---

Look Max

I did what you told me but nothing

```
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx) 
Dim tokenObject As Object = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar() 
tokenReader = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow) 
tokenReader.Read() 
fileToken = DirectCast(tokenReader(1), Byte()) 
filePathName = tokenReader.GetSqlString(3)
```

And the Transaction starts far upper of this command

And never stops

---

```
Dim imGUID As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
Dim imImage As Byte() = New Byte(imStream.Length) {}
Dim bytesRead As Integer = imStream.Read(imImage, 0, imStream.Length)
Dim SecondColumnNames As String = _
            imTable(1) & "_GUID, " & _
            imTable(1) & "_" & imTable(0) & "_ID"
Dim SecondFieldsValues As String = "'" & imGUID.ToString & "', '" & AbsRecord & "'"
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & imTable(1) & _
            " (" & SecondColumnNames & ")  VALUES (" & SecondFieldsValues & ")", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
RemoteSQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@" & imTable(1) & "_GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = imGUID
  RemoteSQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@" & imTable(1) & "_Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imImage
  RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM " & imTable(1), RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
Dim tokenObject As Object = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar()
tokenReader = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
tokenReader.Read()
```

As you can see i put again the FROM claus.

But please look what i'm receiving in the reader

---

tokenReader.Depth            0

tokenReader.FieldCount           1

tokenReader.HasRows          True

tokenReader.IsClosed             False

tokenReader.Item             In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

tokenReader.RecordsAffected -1

---

As you can see here i have only one column to read and nothing else

I really don't know if that is helpful but anyway i put it there

tokenReader.VisibleFieldCount   1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN said](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934014.aspx) you should

- do this inside TRANSACTION
- do "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()" without any "FROM TABLE"

---

There is a sample in [Working with FILESTREAM using VB .NET By Yan Pan](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3802241/Working-with-FILESTREAM-using-VB-NET.htm):

```
' Obtain a transaction context. All FILESTREAM BLOB operations occur '
' within a transaction context to maintain data consistency. '
Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = 
    sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("mainTranaction")
sqlCommand.Transaction = transaction
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()"
Dim obj As Object = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
Dim txContext As Byte() = Nothing
If Not obj.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
    txContext = DirectCast(obj, Byte())
Else
    Throw New System.Exception("GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() failed")
End If

' Obtain a handle that can be passed to the Win32 FILE APIs. '
Dim sqlFileStream As New SqlFileStream(filePath, txContext, FileAccess.Write)

' Converting the image to a byte array. '
' Please change C:\Spire.jpg to your image file path. '
Dim byteImg As Byte()
byteImg = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Spire.jpg")
'Write the image file to the FILESTREAM BLOB. '
sqlFileStream.Write(byteImg, 0, byteImg.Length)

' Close the FILESTREAM handle. '
sqlFileStream.Close()

' Commit the write operation that was performed on the FILESTREAM BLOB. ' 
sqlCommand.Transaction.Commit()
```

Try to change your code according to sample:

- filePath variable is initiated before opening file transaction
- there is a simple "SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()" command for file context
- there is a null check and DirectCast(obj, Byte()) to cast value into byte
- not sure if it make difference, but `SqlFileStream` is opening with `txContext`, not `txContext.Value`

**UPDATE**
How I understand the problem:

`filePathName` - filename from where we will open filestream. this value should be selected from some field of some your table. If you don't know what [table].[field] it is, see inside db table values and find where file path are saved.

`fileToken` - filestream transaction context. should be selected in separate command execute, and casted to Byte.

---

[SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) means when you do things like

```
RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & imTable(0) & " WHERE " 
    & imTable(0) & "_Code = " & "'" & imParam(1) 
    & "'", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
```

in codebehind and `imParam` is an URL parameter value than someone may play a bad joke with you putting "'; DROP TABLE users;" in it which may resolve into

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_Code = ''; DROP TABLE users;
```

Comment: Look I did what you told to do but i receive the same problem
Please look at my next post it has more particular tips for it

Comment: You can select the transaction context in the same command. Doing it separately will degrade performance: additional round trip to the server.